# Property coordinate not found on object of type CLLocationManager

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapkit, core-location

I am building a small app that tracks a users location, stores their location data in an array, and draws a polyline in an MKOverlay.

I think I have everything setup correctly but I am getting the above mentioned error: `Property coordinate not found on object of type CLLocationManager`

**ViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <CLLocationManagerDelegate, MKMapViewDelegate, MKOverlay> {

CLLocationManager *locationManager;
NSMutableArray *trackingPointArray;

MKMapRect routeRect;
MKPolylineView *routeLineView;
MKPolyline *routeLine;

}

- (IBAction)startFollowing:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)stopFollowing:(id)sender;

@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView;

@end
```

**Problem Code**

```
    CLLocationDegrees Latitude = currentLocation.coordinate.latitude;
    CLLocationDegrees Longitude = currentLocation.coordinate.longitude;
    CLLocationCoordinate2D locationCoordinates = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(Latitude, Longitude);
```

I thought maybe this was because I had no object declared on my .h but when I added

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) CLLocation *coordinate;
```

I got a new error: Property type `CLLocation` is incompatible with type `CLLocationCoordinate2D` inherited from `MKOverlay`

From everything I can see, this should be working but of course as it currently stands this fails to build. A push in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was right in front of me

Further up I had:

```
CLLocationManager *currentLocation = [locations lastObject];
```

Wrong wrong wrong!!!

I should have had:

```
CLLocation *currentLocation = [locations lastObject];
```